# EntityFramework and aspnetdb

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, relational-database

I'm trying to use entity framework together with the default membership "aspnetdb" database.

I'm having trouble with membership and user tables, since I'd like to have a navigational property from membership to user.

I feel like I've tried every combination of fluent api mapping, but I must be missing something - or maybe it just can't be done, when the foreign key is UserId - which is the primary key of both tables as well?

Here's what I have:

```
public class Membership {
        [Key]
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

public class User {
        [Key]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public String UserName { get; set; }

        //public virtual Membership Membership { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }



protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Membership>().ToTable("dbo.aspnet_Membership");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("dbo.aspnet_Roles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("dbo.aspnet_Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                            .HasMany(m => m.Roles)
                            .WithMany(m => m.Users)
                            .Map(m => {
                                m.ToTable("aspnet_UsersInRoles");
                                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                            });
            //modelBuilder.Entity<Membership>()
            //    .HasRequired(m => m.User);
                //.WithOptionalPrincipal(m => m.Membership).Map(m=>m.MapKey("UserId"));
            Database.SetInitializer<EkomiteDBC>(null);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

The roles are set up fine, and works, but no matter how I try and define the connection between membership and user I keep getting different mapping errors.

I know I'm probably missing something basic, can anyone help?

EDIT: The problem is, it seems, that both "membership" and "users" tables have the primary key "UserID".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Membership>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.User)
            .WithOptional(u => u.Membership);
```

Anyway you should not do that at all. Use standard membership API for accessing these tables. These tables are not yours they belong to membership / role API and handling them through EF just removes or breaks functionality the API provides out of the box - in general it will reduce the security because those tables will be available for update in EF and business rules from Membership / Role API will not be enforced.

Comment: I need to do this exactly because they will be available for update and manipulation through EF. We basically use this database solely to accommodate a dependent system, but we need to be able to write custom applications to work with these data. And thank you - that was quite possibly the ONLY combination I didn't try :)

Comment: Can't do LINQ over standard membership API. Requirement if you simply want to show the email unfortunately.